# ElasticSearch_dsl issue

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I am trying to integrate elastic within the django existing db. but within the site packages i am facing Errors on running the local server or to view the respective commands.

Below is the versions of packages i m using,
django-elasticsearch-dsl==0.5.0, elasticsearch==6.3.0 and elasticsearch-dsl==6.2.1.

```
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "Desktop/envs/elas_envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "Desktop/envs/elas_envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/homeDesktop/envs/elas_envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/Desktop/envs/elas_envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/Desktop/envs/elas_envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home//Desktop/envs/elas_envs/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/Desktop/envs/elas_envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .documents import DocType  # noqa
  File "/home/Desktop/envs/elas_envs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/documents.py", line 8, in <module>
    from elasticsearch_dsl.document import DocTypeMeta as DSLDocTypeMeta
ImportError: cannot import name 'DocTypeMeta'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: unistall this package  elasticsearch-dsl , just use one dsl package

Comment: On uninstalling the elasticsearch-dsl package, the dependency issue for django-elasticsearch-dsl arises..,

Comment: I've this issue, too. Not find a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Like described in [this issue](https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl/issues/119) this is the result of lack of backward compatibility of `elasticsearch-dsl` package, starting from version `6.2.0` onwards.
Temporary solution is to just use older version of package, prior to breaking changes:

`pip install elasticsearch-dsl==6.1.0`

Hopefully this will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

This question is from almost two years ago but this could help others. In latest versions of django_elasticsearch_dsl you need to use Document:

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import (
    Document,
    fields,
    Index,
)
```